# How do I let the user set the row size and column size of a 2D Vector?

Tags: c++, oop, matrix, vector

I have a 2D vector underneath my private section; I'm trying to use the `fill2dVector()` function and allow a user to input the number of rows and columns. I was thinking of doing it two ways:

I tried doing something like this:

```cpp
private
    size_t numRows, numCols;
    vector<vector<int> > data(numRows,vector<int> (numCols,0));
```

But, that gives me an error: `numRows is not a type`, and VS wants me to write a function definition for data even though there was an option to do this automatically it would lead to more errors.

The second thing I tried was to just have a vector there and just resize it to whatever the user chose as their rows and columns. When I tried doing `data.resize(numRows,numCols);`, I got the error: `no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::resize [with _Ty=std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>]" matches the argument list`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix();

    void fill2dVector();

    void display2dVector() const;

private:
    size_t numRows, numCols;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > data;
};

Matrix::Matrix()
{
}

void Matrix::display2dVector() const
{
}

void Matrix::fill2dVector()
{
    std::cout << "   How many rows? ";
    std::cin >> numRows;

    std::cout << "How many columns? ";
    std::cin >> numCols;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "*** numRows = " << numRows << ", " << "numCols = " << numCols << std::endl;
    data.resize(numRows,numCols);
    std::cout << "*** rowSize = " << data.size() << ", " << "colSize = " << data[0].size() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the size of the matrix:" << std::endl;

    Matrix matrix;
    matrix.fill2dVector();

}
```

Comment: 2d vectors don't work like that, in C++. You have to resize() the first dimension to the number of rows, then iterate over it and resize() each row, individually. Or, some shortcuts can be made using `clear()` and `insert()`. For more information, see your C++ book, which should have a detailed chapter on using and initializing vectors; stackoverflow.com is not really a replacement for a C++ book.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik will look into it; currently, i've been reading articles on the web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could overwrite `data` in `fill2dVector`,

```
data = vector<vector<int>>(numRows, vector<int>(numCols, 0));
```